# Puppet: loops for creating file and symlink simultaneously

Tags: puppet

I would like to parse array and create files and symlink in another directory.
I can create files in `sites-available` and would like to create a symlink in `sites-enabled`
Could you prompt me on how I can do it, please? Can I do at once?

```
  $domainsnames.each |String $domain| {
    file {"/etc/nginx/sites-available/${domain}.conf":
      # ensure  => link,
      content => template('nginx_on_templates/virtualhost.conf.erb'),
      # target  => "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/${domain}.conf",
      mode    => '0644',
      owner   => 'root',
      group   => 'root',
    }
  }
```

Thank in advance,
Rostyslav

Comment: It appears you already did everything yourself. Use the `file` resource you created (with a more precise `ensure` parameter) for the file creation, and another with your parameters uncommented for the symlink.

Comment: Thank you Matt. However, If I uncomment I have got wart: `"You cannot specify more than one of content, source"`

Comment: I do not see a `file` resource with `source` in your question though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably are managing both `sites-available` and `sites-enabled`, and you want to simulate what `a2ensite enable <site-name>` does, correct?

In that case, you have something like:

```rb
 $domainsnames.each |String $domain| {
    file {"/etc/nginx/sites-available/${domain}.conf":
      ensure  => file,
      content => template('nginx_on_templates/virtualhost.conf.erb'),
      mode    => '0644',
      owner   => 'root',
      group   => 'root',
    }
    file {"/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/${domain}.conf":
      ensure  => link,
      target  => "/etc/nginx/sites-available/${domain}.conf",
    }
  }
```

I also recommend you taking a look at the [puppetlabs/apache](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apache) module, where you don't have to manage the `.conf` yourself, but you manage the configurations for your virtual host:

e.g.:

```rb
apache::vhost { 'user.example.com':
  port          => '80',
  docroot       => '/var/www/user',
  docroot_owner => 'www-data',
  docroot_group => 'www-data',
}
```